# Grouping JSON data from DJango QuerySet

Tags: json, django, datatables

I have this result(JSON) from my Django `QuerySet`:

```
{
    "high": [{
        "counthigh": 27,
        "brgy_locat": "Barangay 6"
    }, {
        "counthigh": 3,
        "brgy_locat": "Mabini"
    }],
    "medium": [{
        "brgy_locat": "Barangay 6",
        "countmedium": 31
    }, {
        "brgy_locat": "Tolosa",
        "countmedium": 9
    }],
    "low": [{
        "brgy_locat": "Barangay 12",
        "countlow": 29
    }, {
        "brgy_locat": "Mabini",
        "countlow": 25
    }, {
        "brgy_locat": "Barangay 9",
        "countlow": 35
    }]
}
```

I wanted to group it by brgy_locat and its values:

```
brgy_locat | countlow | countmedium | counthigh
```

Mainly because, I am using datatables.

BTW, here's my views.py:

```
response_data = {} 
response_data["medium"] = list(BuildingStructure.objects.filter(geom__intersects=getgeom_medium).values( 'brgy_locat').annotate(countmedium=Count('brgy_locat'))) 
response_data["high"] = list(BuildingStructure.objects.filter(geom__intersects=getgeom).values('brgy_locat').annotate( counthigh=Count('brgy_locat'))) 
response_data["low"] = list(BuildingStructure.objects.filter(geom__intersects=getgeom_low).values('brgy_locat').annotate( countlow=Count('brgy_locat'))) 
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: How are you getting JSON from a QuerySet? And what database are you using?

Comment: From a HttpResponse and I'm using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you're looking for within a QuerySet. You'll need to manipulate your data in python. Here's one way to do it. It assumes that each element won't have conflicting keys. Meaning `high`, `medium`, `low`'s dictionaries will only have the `counthigh`, etc key in them. Besides `brgy_locat` of course.

```
data = {
    "high": [{
        "counthigh": 27,
        "brgy_locat": "Barangay 6"
    }, {
        "counthigh": 3,
        "brgy_locat": "Mabini"
    }],
    "medium": [{
        "brgy_locat": "Barangay 6",
        "countmedium": 31
    }, {
        "brgy_locat": "Tolosa",
        "countmedium": 9
    }],
    "low": [{
        "brgy_locat": "Barangay 12",
        "countlow": 29
    }, {
        "brgy_locat": "Mabini",
        "countlow": 25
    }, {
        "brgy_locat": "Barangay 9",
        "countlow": 35
    }]
}

result = {}

for category in data.values():
    for element in category:
        key = element.pop('brgy_locat')
        if key not in result:
            result[key] = {}
        result[key].update(element)
```

Then result should be:

```
{
    "Barangay 6": {
        "counthigh": 27,
        "countmedium": 31
    }, 
    "Mabini": {
        "counthigh": 3,
        "countlow": 25
    },
    "Tolosa": {
        "countmedium": 9
    },
    "Barangay 12":{
        "countlow": 29
    },
    "Barangay 9": {
        "countlow": 35
    }
}
```

Comment: You run that same bit of looping logic on it.

Comment: A bit help, how to I access them in my JS?

Comment: You should create a new question for that one. It's not related to this one and you'll need to provide more details about your use case.

Comment: Would you mind updating the answer so that it will output e.g.,`{0: brgy_locat:"Tolosa",countlow:9,countmedium:7,counthigh:8}`.